# Which editor is used to make .agss file

Tags: xml, notepad++

I am using MetaMoJi Corporation eYACHO apps . They has option to customize data by XML code. But they use the extension of XML is .agss . I don't know what is the full meaning of agss . Also they used Notepad++ editor . But I need to choose save as type in Notepad++. If I choose extension markup language , then there is no .agss format. Also I can not import xml code in eYACHO apps without .agss format. Only .agss file can be import in eYACHO. Which editor is use to make .agss file? Is it XML file? Because the code is written in xml.

Comment: Edit it in Notepad++. Save as plain text, and type in  the .agss extension when you save.

Comment: Thank You. Can you please tell me why use .agss format? what is the advantages to use this. Because the code is in XML . If I save the code in .xml format, eYACHO can not find this during import.

Comment: Ask MetaMoJi. They decided to do so. I didn't. :-) I can just tell you that XML is plain text, and Notepad++ works with plain text, and will save it as plain text with any extension you want to type. I have no idea why they decided to use the .agss extension.